# About SVM cost and gamma parameters tuning

Tags: classification, svm, kernel-trick, hyperparameter

I am using `R` and `e1071` package to tune a C-classification SVM.

My question is: regardless of the kernel type (linear, polynomial, radial basis or sigmoidal), is there any good criterion to choose the range in which cost and $\gamma$ parameters should range over and/or to choose what the granularity should be (that is, as an example, `gamma = 10 ^ (1:2)` or `gamma = 1:2` or `gamma = 100 ^ (1:2)`)?

I add a second question: can `tune.svm()` return the best kernel type, too?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using a grid search, it may be easier to use something like the Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm (which I believe has an R implementation) and use that to minimise the model selection criterion, and then you don't need to worry about the limits at all.  Do minimise a continuous criterion though, for example the hinge loss on the test examples or radius-margin bound, rather than the test error rate (as that will be rather noisy and hard to optimised.  Don't optimise the hyper-parameters too much though as it is also possible to get overfitting in model selection as well as in fitting the SVM.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestment, Dikran Marsupial. Let you have to decide which is the best kernel type and the best value of cost and $\gamma$ parameters: what would you optimize first, according to which criterion and why?

Comment: Linear and RBF kernels are good reasonable choices to look at first, however the choice of kernel is very much data-dependent.  The Nelder Mead method can optimise both parameters simultaneously, which is generally the best option.  I rarely use SVMs these days, as Kernel Logistic Regression gives estimates of probability, which I find more useful than a binary decision for most real-world problems.  Alternatively I use kernel ridge regression (AKA LS-SVM).  The training procedure is much more straightforward, and you can get cross-validation almost for free, which I use for model selection.

Comment: Is the Kernel Logistic Regression like a non parametric Logit model (or similar to that one)? I will try it, thank you. Could you suggest me any `R` package with KLR?

Comment: KLR is essentially just a logistic regression model made non-linear using the same "kernel trick" used in the SVM.  I am a MATLAB user, so I'm afraid I can't recommend a suitable R package.  I've been meaning to learn R, so I may write one, one day!

Comment: Please, take a look at this: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/np/vignettes/np.pdf just from page 17 to page 19; is that similar to what you explained to me?

Comment: To counteract overfitting in model selection, make sure you choose parameters based on a validation set before considering accuracy on the test set (in CV or predefined sets). Also, modern approaches from Bayesian optimization tend to outperform Nelder-Mead.

Comment: @Dougal I suspect this is a "no free-lunch" issue, and there is unlikely to be any method that dominates a-priori.  They key issue is to avoid optimising the hyper-parameters too much, which can be done by both frequentist and Bayesian approaches.